# Viewport focus (pivot) point different in Layout and Sculpt mode

Tags: interface, sculpting

While I was sculpting, the Viewport pivot point moved way out the object all of a sudden. In layout mode, it is still inside the object, meaning when I pan, it moves my object. But in sculpt mode, it’s like moving a camera that is very far away from my object. What happened here and is there a quick fix?

Kindest regards,
Habib

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've moved the pivot point for your viewport (not to be confused with any camera in the screen).

In Sculpt Mode you can still use the numpad period (.) key to focus the view (and pivot) back to your object. This should fix the error.

Alternatively, use the Home key to refocus the view and pivot on your whole scene.

Comment: Hey Onyx‍♂️ Thank you so much for your suggestions, this helped me immensely!!